# "Could not read schema model header information from package."

Tags: c#, sql-server, dacpac

I try to deploy a .dacpac via Code in Visual Studio C# into my MS Sql database  and whenever the .dacpac file is about to be deployed, it throws this error:

Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServicesException: 'Could not read schema model header information from package.'

SqlPackageException: The model version '2.9' is not supported.

Ive gone through several threads and tried to fix it but nothing could solve my error.

I imported Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac-x86 Nuget Package for the using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac; namespace.

I have SSMS18 installed too.

I can also deploy the same .dacpac file when I do it via Visual Studios SQL Server Object Explorer (No error there and works perfectly) , but I need to do it in code..

Connection strings and file paths all are correct.

This is the method I am using (last line is where error appears):

```
        var dbServices = new DacServices(connString);

        var dbPackage = DacPackage.Load(new FileStream(dacpacPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), DacSchemaModelStorageType.Memory, FileAccess.Read);

        var dbDeployOptions = new DacDeployOptions
        {
            CreateNewDatabase = true
        };

        dbServices.Deploy(dbPackage, NewDBName.Text, upgradeExisting: true, options: dbDeployOptions);
```

Has anyone a possible solution for this please?

Answer (score 0):

In my case a wrong version of dacpack Dll (`Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll`) was loaded. It was loaded from x86 for SQL 2015 `\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin` instead of x64 for SQL 2017 `\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin`.